# Printing tree shows weird characters

Tags: c++, tree

I'm a beginner in C++ and need help with this problem.
It's a simple create, read and print program based on a tree structure.

The problem is, when I print the tree it shows me weird information made from numbers and letters. It probably doesn't read the right memory data.
I wrote a recursive "create" function that reads console inputs and adds them to the tree structure.
The function works like this:

1. read console input;
2. if input is null then return NULL;
3. else assign input to node value(in this case "info");
4. the function "calls itself" and goes from left to right(down the left branch, then up to the root, then down the right branch).

Basically, The function checks left followers as it goes down, and right followers as it goes up.

Example: A tree like 1->root, 2->left follower, 3->right follower is read like this: 1,2,0,0,3,0,0. The first two 0s assign NULL value node "2"'s followers and thus makes the function go back to the root and down the right branch.

A more complex tree like: 1->root,2->left of "1",4->left of "2",5->right of "4",3-> right of "1"; 7->left of "3", is read like this: 1,2,4,0,5,0,0,0,3,7,0,0,0.

The "read" function reads left->root->right, and works the same as the "create" function.

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct nod
{
    int info;
    nod *left,*right;
} *tree;
nod * create()
{
    int n;
    nod*r;
    cin>>n;
    if(n==0)
        return NULL;
    r=new nod;
    r->info=n;
    r->left=create();
    r->right=create();
    return r;
}

void read(nod *r)
{
    if(r)
    {
        read(r->left);
        cout<<r<<" ";
        read(r->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    tree =new nod;
    tree=create();
    read(tree);
    return 0;
}
```

input is done like this: 1,2,3,0,4,0,0,5,0,0,6,7,0,0,0.

Thanks.

Comment: You have a memory leak in your code. You first allocate memory for `tree` but then you _overwrite_ the pointer, so you loose the original allocated memory.

Comment: @DarkFalcon That's the problem, so why not put it as an answer that can be upvoted and accepted?

Comment: "the function "calls itself" and goes from left to right" - This is called recursion. A recursive function is one that calls itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem with the output that I see is that you are printing `r`, which is a pointer. I think you meant `r->info`.

Comment: Yup, that's it, thanks for the answer, and thanks too all the rest who  considered the question. Apologies if my description is ambiguous in any way.  Hope this helps anyone with similar obvious problems :), or are just trying to create and print a tree.